# How to create a Dependency between two Azure DevOps projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops, project-management

Consider I have multiple projects in Azure. One might be a standard library of some kind which all other projects rely on. Because of Team Management one "big" Project containing all the projects is not a possibility.

The question is how I can work simultaneously on both the Standard Library and one of the inheriting applications in one Visual Studio Frame. Furthermore how to lay out my Azure Architecture to make clear that an azure project (with its own repository, etc) depends on another.

My goal is to commit changes in the Standard Library separately to changes in the inheriting library and that the inheriting library always uses the latest state of the Standard Library's repository.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using .net (similar is for java, node.js, python) you can use nuget packages. More information how to create nuget package repository can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops).

So each time when project A is [built](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) it can produce nuget package

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    packDestination: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Then you can install those packages in your projects.

And during build you will just restore them

```
# Restore project
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
```